# Django ModelForm not submitting

Tags: python, django, modelform

The views are rendering the correct values to the template and there are no errors when I try to submit the form. Instead when I try to submit the form nothing happens.
[image: Views]
[image: HTML]
[image: Forms]
[image: Models]
[image: Urls]

Let me know if you guys need more pictures or information, and thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Please show your code as text, not pictures

Comment: At a quick glance, this problem is because you are comparing the request method to `'post'` rather than the correct `'POST'`